# Combine list of indices in R

Tags: r, indexing

Assuming that I have multiple indices in form of a list, how can I combine these quickly with help of the '&' operator to one common index (over all lists)? Edit: I tried to use do.call, but it does not seem to work in this case?

code example:

```
set.seed(24)
xlist <- list()
for (i in (1:50)){

    xlist[[i]] <- matrix(sample(c(T,F),25,TRUE,c(0.5,0.5)),5,5)

}
```

I would like to have one 5 x 5 index with TRUE and FALSE values only as a result of the single indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `&`

```
Reduce(`&`, xlist)
```

Comment: Ahh Reduce...why was I only checking do call all the time. Thanks!